# Remove pair duplicates Haskell

Tags: haskell

Giving a list of pairs, for example

```
[(1, 2), (1, 3), (1, 4), (2, 1), (3, 1), (4, 1)]
```

So, I am trying to remove the pair duplicates, I consider a pair to be duplicate if (x, y) == (y, x), for example: (1, 2) with (3, 1)

I am generating the list with a comprehension list, it is derived from one single list

```
MyList = [(intA, intB) | x <- integerList, y <- integerList, x /= y]
integerList = [1, 2, 3];
```

Please note that the first thing I wrote is just an example of what I want to happen and it is not the output of the comprehension list above.

I recently started using Haskell, how would I approach the problem? What would be the best choice? I tried using map, but without success, should I combine a map with a foldl / foldr that uses reverse inside it? How would I do that?

Comment: typo? `(1, 2) with (3, 1)`

Comment: First write `isPairDuplicate :: (Int,Int) -> (Int, Int) -> Bool` (then post it in your question so we know what you're talking about).

Comment: Then I would suggest thinking about writing a recursive solution which uses pattern matching on lists, and maybe `filter` if you're feeling crazy.

Answer (score 8):

This is a perfect time to use [Hoogle](http://www.haskell.org/hoogle)! Let's think about what you're looking for. To remove duplicates, we want something that takes a list `[a]` and removes things from it, returning `[a]` based on some predicate `a -> a -> Bool`. This means we're looking for a function with the following form:

```
ourFunction :: (a -> a -> Bool) -> [a] -> [a]
```

We can actually search [Hoogle](http://www.haskell.org/hoogle) using the function signature, `(a -> a -> Bool) -> [a] -> [a]`, and the first result is `nubBy`, which does exactly what we want!

That being said, you don't need to use this to fix your problem. You're already on the right track. Think about what you're asking -- you want no duplicate tuples where `(x, y) == (y, x)`. So just choose whether or not you want `y < x` or the other way around, and use this in your list comprehension:

```
> let fn xs = [(a, b) | a <- xs, b <- xs, a < b]
> fn [1, 2, 3]
[(1,2),(1,3),(2,3)]
```

If you need both lists (one with duplicates and one without) I'd suggest using two separate list comprehensions. It is less performant, as the list comprehension as you have it written is O(n^2), but it's much cleaner and easier to learn from, in my opinion.

Comment: Here's one that doesn't require an `Ord` instance on elements and doesn't do extra work by producing wrong elements and then removing them: `fn xs = [(a, b) | a:xs' <- tails xs, b <- xs']`. I've used this standard trick or a slight variant of it quite a few times in real code. Of course it has the same problem yours does: if the input list has duplicates, the output will, too.

Answer (score 4):

```
import Data.List(nubBy)
import Data.Tuple(swap)

nubBy (\x y -> x==y || swap x == y) [(1, 2), (1, 3), (1, 4), (2, 1), (3, 1), (4, 1)]
[(1,2),(1,3),(1,4)]
```

or write your own versions

Comment: however, better to solve the problem at the source within list comprehension.  I answered the question based on the title and first paragraph description.

Answer (score 0):

It is not answering the questions directly, but there is a simpler solution that applies to this case (numerical tuples), just to add one more filter when generating the list to make sure the latter element is always larger than the previous element.

```
MyList = [(x, y)| x <- integerList, y <- integerList, x /= y, x < y]
```